# How to subclass a ViewController which has IBOutLet and IBAction from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, subclassing

In order to simplify my question please consider following scenario.

`FirstViewController` has a `UILable` which is "connected" as IBOutlet from storyBoard.

`SecondViewController` which is a subclass of `FirstViewController` also has a `UILable`, but has one more `UIButton`. It has a separate represent in the storyBoard.

I don't know whether it is correct or not.

I ctr+drag the `UILable` from the viewController of the `SecondViewController` to the `IBOutlet` in the `FirstViewController`.m file.

Working like champ, the association is correct for me. But I still don't know whether it is the correct way to do so. And will it have any bad effect to my `viewContorller`.

Thanks

Comment: It is a correct way. FirstViewController will behave as a BaseViewController from which you are extending your SecondViewController. This is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also heard some other way while people using xib files.

Comment: It will work fine. No worries.